# Handling 404 error in Next.js deploying with NginX

Tags: nginx, next.js, deployment, next.js13

I recently introduced internationalization to my Next.js project using `next-intl`, leading to a change in the file structure to `app/[locale]` from  `src/app`. Previously, when deploying the project using Nginx, a simple `location` directive in the Nginx configuration was sufficient.

However, after restructuring for internationalization, I've noticed that I now have to specifically set `location/_next/static` in my Nginx configuration. Without this, the application throws 404 errors, seemingly unable to locate the static files.

Before introducing `next-intl`, the application worked fine with just a `location` directive. I'm curious as to why this change is necessary. Why does Nginx now require a specific rule for `_next/static` after the introduction of internationalization in a Next.js project? What is the underlying reason for this change in behavior?

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated, especially if there are best practices for handling such a deployment scenario.